# Intent for sending email opens drive not gmail on some devices although gmail is installed

Tags: android, android-intent, gmail

i have the following problem.

When launching an intent like this:

```
   final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

   emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "hello");     
   emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
   // uris is a ArrayList<Uri> that links to some images in the asset folder
   // everything works fine with those attachments on the nexus 4
   emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

   this.startActivity(emailIntent);
```

It shows me a collection of suitible apps on my Nexus 4 (running 4.2.2)

If i run the code on a Nexus 7 (running 4.2.2 aswell) it does not show me the option to use gmail even though its installed and running fine.

Any Ideas on this?

edit: the only real difference that i can think of is, that the nexus 7 has 2 user accounts set up on the device. Could that be related to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS: This works for me! Modify it according to ur needs!

```
Uri file_uri = Uri.fromFile(fileLocation);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file_uri);
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Complete Action Using"));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(ExportReport.this, "There are no email clients installed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```